# OpenCL: does it play well with OpenMP, can I connect other languages to it, etc

Tags: openmp, opencl

The 1.0 spec for OpenCL just came out a few days ago (Spec is [here](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/)) and I've just started to read through it.  I want to know if it plays well with other high performance multiprocessing APIs like OpenMP ([spec](http://openmp.org/wp/)) and I want to know what I should learn.  So, here are my basic questions:

1. If I am already using OpenMP, will that break OpenCL or vice-versa?
2. Is OpenCL more powerful than OpenMP?  Or are they intended to be complementary?
3. Is there a standard way of connecting an OpenCL program to a standard C99 program (or any other language)?  What is it?
4. Does anyone know if anyone is writing an OpenCL book?  I'm reading the spec, but I've found books to be more helpful.

Answer (score 7):

OpenMP and OpenCL are distinct, but can be made to work together.  Neither of them should "break" the other.

For the sake of argument, let's assume there's a tradeoff between minimizing changes to an existing codebase and performance or computing power.  OMP is "easy" in that you can apply it "magically" to embarrassingly parallel problems with a quick pragma or two.

OpenCL introduces brand new high-level concepts beyond typical OS threading models.  Khronos probably doesn't want to say it out loud, but its genesis is in NVIDIA's CUDA.  If you want to see how it works today, download the CUDA SDK and start playing.  If you don't have any NVIDIA GPUs, don't worry, there's a GPU-emulator software option.  OpenCL is a handy abstraction of a GPU that should apply to CPUs, DSPs, "accelerators" (Khronos' nickname for IBM's CellBE and probably Intel's Larrabee).

OpenCL is not supposed to be "written directly in C99".  It's referred to as a C99 extension since its syntax is similar/identical to C99 with some new keywords.  You cannot call libc (or any other library) from a kernel.

You could use both, but theoretically, OpenCL should be "better" (in that it's portable to more computing devices) if you're willing to port your code.  You can not use OpenMP pragmas in an OpenCL kernel.

See also:

- http://wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL
- [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home.html)
- [LLVM](http://llvm.org/)

Answer (score 4):

For the most part OpenMP and OpenCL are independent from each other.  They are both ways of giving the developer access to parallelism on their platform.

OpenMP is designed to work well with multiple (identical) processors, where work that is approximately equal can be (nearly) automatically farmed out between them.

OpenCL is a somewhat different beast, in that it is really shines when working with special co-processor hardware.  It will allow you to offload some of the heavy-duty number crunching to the GPU or some other co-processor like in the Cell.  However, it was also built with the idea that it could be used to harness other main processors, as are now common in multi-core computers.  I would consider this feature to be secondary, and if this is all you intend to use OpenCL for, I would not recommend using OpenCL.

That said, I'd guess it would be somewhat challenging, though definitely not impossible to get OpenMP and OpenCL to work together in the same problem.

The first thing to think about is what work you're giving to OpenCL.  This would definately be a case where you would only want OpenCL to run on the GPU/Co-processor...not on the other main-processors/cores, since OpenMP is alreay using those.  It wouldn't (shouldn't) cause application errors to run OpenCL and OpenMP on the same main processor, but it will cause un-desirable scheduling where both the OpenMP and OpenCL run slower because they spend a good chunk of their time switching back and fourth between each other.  This would also happen if you run any other processor-hungry process on the same core at the same time.

The other big thing to think about is how you're going to schedule tasks that do run on the Co-processor.  Its true that you can feed a lot of work into one of the modern GPUs, but there are lots of things to think about with the pipeline and memory usage.  What you wouldn't want to happen is to have 8 different OpenMP threads each trying to send their own work to the Co-Processor at the same time.  I would recommend having only one thread that manages all the interactions with the Co-Processor, so it can make sure to feed it work in an efficient manner.

That said, I'm sure there are programs that have multiple types of tasks happening at the same time, where one type of task could always be farmed out to the Co-Processor and another kind of task could be handled by the multi-core main processor.  This would be a fine example of a time to mix OpenMP and OpenCL.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. ?
2. ?
3. OpenCL is supposed to be written directly in C99 afaik? There are header files available now for it anyhow.
4. ?

Answer (score 0):

By the way, [there is a work](http://www.multicoreinfo.com/research/papers/2009/ppopp09-9-omp2gpu-lee.pdf) about openMp to gpgpu using CUDA.